# Preserving One Key Recovery feature while migrating to a smaller SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, migration

The question is simple, but the answer might be complicated as I am not targeting One Key Recovery feature of a specific vendor, I'm searching for a answer in general.

Suppose I'm migrating from a 1 TB HDD to an SSD, considering the high prices of SSDs, I might opt in for a 240 GB model.

Now I'm light on storage, so my C drive has only 100 GB of content, so the size of my newly-purchased SSD will not be a problem for this migration.

Now my problem is, how to do the migration without reinstalling Windows and also preserving the One Key Recovery feature from my laptop vendor?

(If the answer is to include details about how One Key Recovery work, that will be even better.)

Answer (score 1):

You can take a backup of your existing Windows installation by using the standard Windows backup tool or EaseUS Todo Backup Free.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/backup-and-restore

Restore this backup to your ssd drive.

Now to get your One Key Recovery Working again, you need a create a hidden recovery partition with ID of 12. This partition must be the third primary partition on your SSD. 
You can use freeware tools like Partition Wizard or Bootice to do this.

Copy the One Key Recovery Files from your old hard disk to your SSD's new hidden partition.

This might help in copying the files from the hidden partition - http://agnipulse.com/2012/10/mount-hidden-partitions-unhiding/

Then you need to run FixASD which fixes the NOVO button your Lenovo Laptop to boot into your Recovery Partition. More details on this here - http://agnipulse.com/2013/12/resize-lenovo-key-recovery-partition-novo-button/

Alternatively you can download Lenovo One Key Recovery Engineer Edition. I have not used this tool and I am not sure about the legal issues about using this tool.
You can find more info about this tool here.

http://www.alltechtalk.net/forum/thread-to-windows-8-upgraders-and-onekey-recovery-users

http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-3000-and-Essential/Disk-Partitioning-and-OneKey-Recovery-Feature/m-p/720819#M36568

http://forum.notebookreview.com/ideapad-essential/688883-how-restore-onekey-recovery-function-after-changing-partition-size-y580-maybe-others.html

Hope this helps.